# Free Map matching benchmark data

Tags: geospatial

I have my own map matching algorithm and I want to compare it's accuracy to some other algorithms. Is there a free trace dataset that has a confirmed match for each trace (ground truth), so I can perform the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty old now, but I'm looking for the same stuff and found this article so far:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7225829

The corresponding dataset (described in this article) can be found here: https://zenodo.org/record/57731#.XDS-Plz0laQ

Maybe this helps you. If you found something yourself in the meantime I would appreciate it if you could share/link it here.

Comment: I have found the linked dataset too. No luck with anything else though.